# Retrieving Multiple data-values Of A List Option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that returns the text output of a data-list. However, I also want to retrieve the `data-value` of these list items for later use. My problem is on line 8, where it appears that my code is not getting each of the selected `data-value` attributes for output. My expected output might look like this:

`TEXT: A-wing, B-Wing DATA: 3,2`

Whereas it currently outputs:

`TEXT: A-wing, B-Wing DATA:`

```js
function testIt(){

var dataA = $('input[name^=shipDraft]').map(function(i, elem) {
    return $(elem).val();
  }).get();

var dataB = $('input[name^=shipDraft]').map(function(i, elem) {
    return $(elem).find(':selected').attr('data-value');
  }).get();
   


console.log("TEXT: "+dataA+" DATA: "+dataB)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<td>
<input type="text" list="shipdraftlist" name="shipDraft"/>
<datalist id="shipdraftlist">
<option data-value="1">X-wing</option>
<option data-value="2">B-Wing</option>
<option data-value="3">A-Wing</option>
</datalist>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" list="shipdraftlist" name="shipDraft" />
</td>

</table>

<button onclick="testIt()">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is in `'input[name^=shipDraft]'` you are not fetching the datalist options, you are fetching the populated values of input filed that are populated on select.

That being said, I tried modifying your `data-value` fetching technique to target actual options of the list like so: `#shipdraftlist option[value='` but I had some problems with it so I just took different approach:

Hope it helps.

```js
function testIt() {
  //get values array
  var dataA = $('input[name^=shipDraft]').map(function(i, elem) {
    return $(elem).val();
  }).get();

  //split array in two
  var dataA1 = dataA[0];
  var dataA2 = dataA[1];

  console.log(dataA1);
  console.log(dataA2);

  // get data-value of the option with value of dataA1
  var dataB1 = $("#shipdraftlist option[value='" + dataA1 + "']").attr('data-value');
  // get data-value of the option with value of dataA2
  var dataB2 = $("#shipdraftlist option[value='" + dataA2 + "']").attr('data-value');

  console.log(dataB1);
  console.log(dataB2);

  //connect them back
  var dataB = dataB1 + "," + dataB2;


  console.log("TEXT: " + dataA + " DATA: " + dataB);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <td>
    <input type="text" list="shipdraftlist" name="shipDraft" />
    <datalist id="shipdraftlist">
<option data-value="1" value="X-wing"></option>
<option data-value="2" value="B-Wing"></option>
<option data-value="3" value="A-Wing"></option>
</datalist>
  </td>

  <td>
    <input type="text" list="shipdraftlist" name="shipDraft" />
  </td>

</table>

<button onclick="testIt()">TEST</button>
```

Or you can do it like this:
where your `dataB` jQuery selector has two conditions using arrays.

```js
function testIt() {

  var dataA = $('input[name^=shipDraft]').map(function(i, elem) {
    return $(elem).val();
  }).get();

  var dataB = $("#shipdraftlist option[value='" + dataA[0] + "'], #shipdraftlist option[value='" + dataA[1] + "']").map(function(i, elem) {
    return $(elem).attr('data-value');
  }).get();


  console.log(dataB);
  console.log("TEXT: " + dataA + " DATA: " + dataB);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <td>
    <input type="text" list="shipdraftlist" name="shipDraft" />
    <datalist id="shipdraftlist">
<option data-value="1" value="X-wing"></option>
<option data-value="2" value="B-Wing"></option>
<option data-value="3" value="A-Wing"></option>
</datalist>
  </td>

  <td>
    <input type="text" list="shipdraftlist" name="shipDraft" />
  </td>

</table>

<button onclick="testIt()">TEST</button>
```

Comment: That certainly works, but I would rather not create multiple vars to store this in, as I might have 2-30 different input fields (sorry, didn't realize I had not mentioned that).

Comment: Once I saw how you grabbed the value I just tossed into into this: `var i, len, dataB;
for (i = 0, len = dataA.length, dataB = []; i < len; i++) {
$("#shipdraftlist option[value='" + rateA[i] + "']").map(function(i, elem) {
    dataB.push($(elem).attr('data-value'));
 
  }).get();
}`

Comment: @littlecoder very nice! I was trying similar thing but it was multiplying my result by length of first variable so I was trying to divide it back:

Comment: var dataB = "";
  for (var i = 0, len = dataA.length; i < len; i++) {
    [].forEach.call(dataA, function(el) {
      dataB += $("#shipdraftlist option[value='" + el + "']").attr('data-value')+",";
    });
  }